# Can't cancel Notification on Accept and Reject Action when Multiple Notification Available

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

First, let me walk you through the process. First, I implement a successful FCM. I have received all type of notification which i want.
The problem is here, notification clear(cancel) When only one notification is available. but more then one same notification are available at that time only one notification will be cancel which is come at last.

I want to do open url on browser on accept and reject

I have attached my code below.

```
private void sendNotification1(String title, String body, String data) {

    int when = new Random().nextInt();

    String url = "http://google.com";
    String url1 = "http://google.com";
    try {
        JSONObject dataObject = new JSONObject(data);
        url = dataObject.getString("acceptUrl");
        url1 = dataObject.getString("declineUrl");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    PendingIntent accceptIntent = NotificationAcceptActivity.getAcceptDismissIntent(this, when, url);
    PendingIntent dismissIntent = NotificationRejectActivity.getAcceptDismissIntent(this, when, url1);


    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notication)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_close_black_24dp, "Reject", dismissIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_check_black_24dp, "Accept", accceptIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(when, notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

public class NotificationAcceptActivity extends Activity {

```
public static final String NOTIFICATION_ID = "NOTIFICATION_ID";
public static final String URL = "ACCEPT_URL";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(URL);
    Intent dismissIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    dismissIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    Log.e("NotificationAccept ", "url:- " + url);
    startActivity(dismissIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(getIntent().getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, -1));
    finish();

}

public static PendingIntent getAcceptDismissIntent(Context context, int notificationId, String url) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationAcceptActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(URL, url);
    intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);
    PendingIntent dismissAcceptIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    return dismissAcceptIntent;
}
```

}

public class NotificationRejectActivity extends Activity {

```
public static final String NOTIFICATION_ID = "NOTIFICATION_ID";
public static final String URL = "ACCEPT_URL";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(URL);
    Intent dismissIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    dismissIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    Log.e("NotificationReject ", "url:- " + url);
    startActivity(dismissIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(getIntent().getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, -1));
    finish();

}

public static PendingIntent getAcceptDismissIntent(Context context, int notificationId, String url) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationRejectActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(URL, url);
    intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);
    PendingIntent dismissAcceptIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    return dismissAcceptIntent;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 should be replaced by each unique number(Request Code) in to all `PendingIntent` object

**Replace**

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

**To**

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, uniqueNumber,
            intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```